# Распаковка apk и работа с исходным кодом

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

Работаю в Android Studio и написал небольшое приложение, после чего запаковал в apk. После решил apk открыть и попробовать изменить, но при декомпиляции выдаёт код с ошибками. Пробовал декомпилировать на разных сайтах а также вручную через dex2jar и jd-gui, но всё равно есть ошибки.
Ошибки следующего характера: у меня есть лайаут (например R.layout.main_layout). В одном случае данную ссылку переименовывает на C0534R.layout.main_layout или вообще 28035684. И это не учитывая такие ошибки как не находит библиотеки, несоответствующая версия Android или Java.
Есть ли более простой способ распаковки и изменения содержимого apk без устранения ошибок в классах и настройки среды? Что если будет большой проект, а исходный код будет утерян, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Если б всё было так просто - пиратки любого ПО выходили бы на следующий день после релиза, а то и вперёд него :D!!!  

Опасностью утери исходников вы должны озаботиться заранее - контроль версий - наше всё!

Comment: То есть, это проблематично? А вообще, насколько возможно воссоздать рабочий исходный код из apk на больших проэктах, и возможно ли это в принципе?

Comment: В принципе - возможно. На практике успех затеи сильно зависит от ваших навыков, опыта и понимания процесса реверсинга (многое придётся исправлять и разбирать вручную), а также от того, кто писал и собирал приложение (на каком языке, насколько позаботился о защите от реверса). Если писал сам, то конечно проще будет - что-то вспомнится, что-то знаешь как должен был написать и т.п.